# "Revision" records in wp_posts have original post type instead of "revision"

Tags: search, post-type, revisions

After seeing some weird hits in my Relevanssi search results I found the following:

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/searching-with-relevanssi-shows-all-revisions

I ran the following on my WordPress database:

```
SELECT * FROM  `wp_posts` 
  WHERE (`post_name` LIKE "%revision%" OR `post_name` LIKE "%autosave%")
  AND `post_status` = "inherit"
  AND `post_parent` !=0
  AND `post_type` !=  "revision"
```

It returned almost 2,000 rows. This means that many of the "revision" records in my wp_posts table are ending up with the wrong post type.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Revision_Management currently states the following:

> Revisions are stored as children of their associated post (the same thing we do for attachments). They are given a post_status of 'inherit', a post_type of 'revision', and a post_name of {parent ID}- revision(-#) for regular revisions and {parent ID}-autosave for autosaves.

In my case these revision records are maintaining the original post type such as "page" or "my-custom-post-type" instead of being changed to "revision."

Any ideas why these records have the wrong post type? I read it may have to do with my custom post type definitions, but if so, why is it happening with "page" records as well?

Comment: This should *not* be happening, could you tell us what plugins you have activated and what theme, and if any of them have been modified/customised from their originals?

Comment: I created a listing of active plugins here: https://gist.github.com/2242493. In addition I had the "Post Type Switcher (1.0)" plugin active until recently.

Comment: It looks like it's the Post Type Switcher plugin. Boo. When that plugin is activated, the revisions get saved with the original post type. When I deactivated the plugin and updated a post, the "revision" post type was correctly applied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried adding an extra clause checking for the revision post type in `function pts_save_post( $post_id, $post ) {` of `post-type-switcher.php` ?

E.g. as taken from trunk and modified:

```
/**
 * Set the post type on save_post but only when editing
 *
 * @since PostTypeSwitcher (0.3)
 * @global string $pagenow
 * @param int $post_id
 * @param object $post
 * @return If any number of condtions are met
 */
function pts_save_post( $post_id, $post ) {
    global $pagenow;

    // Only show switcher when editing
    if ( ! in_array( $pagenow, pts_allowed_pages() ) )
        return;

    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE )
        return;

    if ( ! isset( $_POST['pts-nonce-select'] ) )
        return;

    if ( ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['pts-nonce-select'], 'post-type-selector' ) )
        return;

    if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) )
        return;

    if ( $_POST['pts_post_type'] == $post->post_type )
        return;

    if ( ! $new_post_type_object = get_post_type_object( $_POST['pts_post_type'] ) )
        return;     

    if ( ! current_user_can( $new_post_type_object->cap->publish_posts ) )
        return;

    if($post->post_type == 'revision')
        return;

    set_post_type( $post_id, $new_post_type_object->name );
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'pts_save_post', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Bueno. This looks like it is working. Thank you!! (See my answer for instructions on fixing a database that has already been affected.)

Answer (score 1):

As of now the Post Type Switcher plugin is causing this problem. ([See this forum post.](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-post-type-switcher-post-revision-records-are-saved-with-incorrect-post_type))

After deactivating the plugin, I ran the following to update the database:

```
UPDATE `wp_posts` set `post_type` = "revision"
  WHERE (`post_name` LIKE "%revision%" OR `post_name` LIKE "%autosave%")
  AND `post_status` = "inherit"
  AND `post_parent` != 0
  AND `post_type` != "revision"
```

WARNING: Backup up your database first! :)

WARNING: If you're on a WordPress network install be sure to change `wp_posts` to `wp_XX_posts` (where "XX" is the id of your site) and run it for each one.